# failed to generate preview for user

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement this from the facebook docs on an Android Emulator.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/

```
OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
action.setProperty("book", "https://example.com/book/Snow-Crash.html");

FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "books.reads", "book")
        .build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

It keeps giving the error message

Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to generate preview for user.

I'm using the FbAndroid-3.9.apk

I've appened the book with a namespace but nothing.

Comment: Answered at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025174/android-facebook-sdf-exception-failed-to-generate-preview-for-user/22030173#22030173

Answer (score 0):

The facebook app story was not setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can set up an open graph action using facebook dialog.

```
OpenGraphObject setObj = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("your app namespace:object type");

setObj.setProperty("title", "Title required");
```

/* For songs content type is music.song. You can search in this link to find content type of your object
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music */

```
                    setObj.getData().setProperty("type", "content type of your object");
                    setObj.setProperty("url", "your url");

                    setObj.setProperty("description", "your description");
                    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
```

/* Your action is the action you setup as open graph for your app */

```
                    action.setType("your app name space:your action");
```

/* Your object name can be a song or something like that */

```
                    action.setProperty("your object name", setObj);
```

/* And finally */

```
                    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(context, action, "your object name").build();
                    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```