# Android Facebook-sdf Exception: Failed to generate preview for user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk

i'm developing a simple android app and i want post a status in facebook using OpenGraphObject and OpenGraphAction.

if i use new `FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)` i have no problem, but when i'm using  `FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder` i got the error:

```
01-09 15:56:29.594  11439-11439/simov.project2.yourcity E/Activity﹕ Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to generate preview for user.
```

**java**

```
public void test(int position){

    File f = (File)mImageAdapter.getItem(position);
    Bitmap myBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
    List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    images.add(myBitmap);
    //Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    //session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSION));

    try {
        addresses = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(mItenerariumState.getCurrentLocation().getLatitude()
                , mItenerariumState.getCurrentLocation().getLongitude()
                , 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OpenGraphObject location = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("yourcity:location");
    if(!addresses.isEmpty()){

        location.setProperty("title", addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
    } else {

        location.setProperty("title", "Unknown place");
    }
    location.setProperty("Description", "I visited this place using YourCity App");

    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setProperty("location", location);


  /*  Request request = Request.newPostOpenGraphActionRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), action, new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            //showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
        }
    });

    request.executeAsync();*/
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "yourcity:visit","location")
            .setApplicationName("YourCity")
            //.setImageAttachmentsForAction(images, true)
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
}
```

Important note, the shareDialog show in the screen by like one second and then disappears without any action

Comment: another issue is if i try to attach an image (commented line) i got the exception:

19:21:40.664    6130-6130/simov.project2.yourcity E/Activity﹕ Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Error retrieving image attachment.

Comment: Try using OpenGraphAction.Factory.createForPost to create your action. Also, if you want to add images, you need to use the setImageAttachmentsForObject or setImageAttachmentsForAction methods in the OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder, and make sure to read the javadocs because you need to add a content provider to your android manifest.

Comment: i have setImageAttachmentsForAction , you can see there, its only commented, and i have in my manifest the content provider :\

 <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider{appid}"
            android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider" />

Comment: @andrealmeida where you be able to solve your problem? I got the same and I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Have been dealing with this error for hours.
Heres how I fixed it.
The Actions and Objects you specified in your code are the ones that cause the problem.

The samples provided on the Facebook developers guide aren't good enough I feel.
Heres a sample code you can use that will work perfectly.
Basically make sure your ObjectType -> eg: video.other is set correctly and your Action type e.g: video.watches is set right.

```
    void sometestCode(){
        OpenGraphObject video = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("video.other");
        video.setTitle("Awesome Video");
        video.setDescription("This video will show you how to make the Opengraph work");

        OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
        action.setProperty("video", video);
        action.setType("video.watches");            

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "video")
                .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

    }
```

Comment: 1. what represents `other` in your code? - e.g: `video.other`- and 2. why do yo use `action.setType("video.watches")` ? The docs say : `actionType - The type of the Open Graph action to be published, which should be the namespace-qualified name of the action type (e.g., "myappnamespace:myactiontype"); this will override the type of the action passed in.` I have used your code but I get the same disappearing dialog.

Comment: Can you please share the link where I can get the updated documents ?

Comment: @AlexAndro: 1. "other" represents a type of video there can be "tv_show" or "movie". 2. You need to specify "myappnamespace" only when it is a custom object or action. If you are using the ones provided by Facebook then you can skip it.

Comment: @Kunu :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share You can also look at Open Graph

Answer (score 1):

We had the exact same error some times ago.
Check you are using the correct action type in OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder.
We fixed the same error just using the correct action type parameter.
In your case you should check if "yourcity:visit" is the name of the action.
Go to developer consolle 
https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/your-app-id/open-graph/action-types/ and click on Get Code for the action you want to implement. Then read the url that should looks like something like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/app_namespace:app_action?...

then use the correct app_action in your code. It should fix!